# How can I fix overlapping of data labels in React Apex Charts?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, apexcharts

I am using React Apex Charts to create a timeline column chart. My data label returns the time frame of the dataset in days - hours - minutes format. But, whenever I zoom in, the labels overlap and are not readable. Is there a property I can set to fix this? I have attached images below.

[image]

[image]